# Creating instance of State in Frege

Tags: haskell, state-monad, frege

In [y-taka-23 adaptation of LYAH](https://github.com/y-taka-23/learn-you-a-frege) I found that most of snippets for Chapter 13 must deal with lack of `State` constructor, for example original Haskell code:

```
randomSt = State random
```

is rewritten as:

```
randomSt = do
    gen <- State.get
    let (x, newGen) = random gen
    State.put newGen
    return x
```

This of course has its own didactic merits! But I wonder if there is another way of creating instance of `State`. I know that this discrepancy between  Frege and Haskell comes from the fact that `State s a` in Frege's `Control.monad.State` module is an abstract data type.  Is it possible to define new concrete data type which derives from it and use its constructor instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you just write a smart constructor?

```
state :: (s -> (a, s)) -> State s a
state f = do
    s <- State.get
    let (x, s') = f s
    State.put s'
    return x
```

Write it once (maybe in a library you make available for download?) and then use it anywhere you need it.

Comment: Yes, this solution seems to mimic  `state` function from Haskell `Control.Monad.Trans.State` as explained in Wikibook [here.](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Understanding_monads/State)

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the construction of some specific state instance with

```
State random
```

is quite elegant, and it's impossible in Frege because the `State` data constructor is not accessible. This is unfortunate, but it also protects you from writing code that depends on some implementation details.

For example, I'm currectly working on a new backend for Frege that utilizes Java lambdas and tries to emit typesafe generic Java code, and in the course of doing this it turned out that I need another representation for State. Thus, in the next Frege release, there simply is no `State` constructor anymore that would take a function as argument.

Despite of this change and the fact that big parts of the compiler consist of State operations, I didn't had to change any single line in the compiler code because of this. And I can alos be sure hat I won't hurt anybody else's code. Big win!

Anyway, I feel like we could include @jcast's smart state constructor in the standard library. (I'd just rewrite the let into a case.)

Comment: That sounds reasonably, but I still don't get how having constructor would break anything.

Comment: @libnull-dev Because the constructor reveals implementation details like that State s a is isomorphic with s->(a,s) , but as I tried to explain this is not necessarily the best implementation. the implementation can't change in a backwards compatible way when you - the stdlib consumer - know the constructor.

Comment: OK, so does it mean that `State` can have different than `State s a` representation?

Comment: The type is of course always State s a. But it doesn't have to be isomorphic with a s -> (a,s) function. And there need not be a constructor with the name State.